# Remaining the same state of a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, timer

So I've made a web app, image below. The app has several tabs which contain different information such as graphs and indicators. The app is made using HTML & Javascript and is **one** document. I have implemented a Javascript timer which, every 60 seconds, loads the exact same webapp but in a different HTML document, just with different values for the graphs etc. This was just to make it easy for me as i don't have a lot of time at the moment. So every minute the web apps graphs will refresh with different data coming from a different document. So basically i have index.html, index2.html and index3.html, all with the same code/webapp but loading different values into the graphs. Heres the code for the timer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},60000);

         $(function () {

         });

         function myTimer()
            {
            window.location.replace("index2.html");
            }

         </script>
```

The only problem with this is that when, for example, index.html reaches 60 seconds and loads index2.html it goes back to the very first tab (Summary), is there anyway to remain on the same tab even though it's loading a different document?

[image]

Comment: Could you load the content into the Metrics Div using `$.ajax()` rather than reloading the whole page?

Comment: Are you using JQuery UI tabs? If so you can set a cookie to persist the selected tab (admittedly I've found it a bit buggy). If you aren't, you'll have to set and read your own cookie manually but it shouldn't be too difficult. You could also redirect to the new index.html with a querystring parameter saying the selected tab and then read that in every time the page loads...

Comment: @Mansfield 'You could also redirect to the new index.html with a querystring parameter saying the selected tab and then read that in every time the page loads' - this sounds like an interesting solution. Any chance you could post an example?

Comment: @BuzzLightyear Matt Browne's answer explains what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

As @JoshuaM pointed out, the best solution would be to use AJAX, but since you seem mostly satisfied with your current method, you could use a hash on the URL to indicate which tab should be active, e.g.:

```
index.html#/metrics
index2.html#/metrics
etc...
```

(I like to put in a leading slash for this sort of thing to distinguish it from a regular anchor link or unexpectedly jumping to an element with the same ID, but in a simple case like this, `index.html#metrics` could work just as well).

The link for the metrics tab would look like this:

```
<a href="#/metrics">Metrics</a>
```

(Keep whatever Javascript you have set up on it to make the tabs work.)

Then, when loading the next page, append the hash to it:

```
var nextPage = 'index2.html';
window.location = nextPage + window.location.hash;
```

Finally, check for the hash when first loading a page:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
//hashes indicating which tab to make active should begin with a slash, e.g. #/metrics
if (hash[1]=='/') {
    var currentTab = hash.substr(2);
    //activate current tab...
}
```

Another alternative would be to use an iframe for the graph content but that would probably require more reworking of your code.

Comment: Looks like the perfect solution, my links arent appending to the URL though!

Comment: That's probably because the event handler for your tabs includes `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`. So you may need to write your own Javascript for the tabs or modify it so that it doesn't do that. If you're open to using a different tab script, you could use the tabs control from Twitter Bootstrap, which is designed to append hash values to the URL.

Comment: It should be `window.location.hash`, not `window.hash` - fixing my answer now.

Comment: Another idea: you could add your own event handler to force the hash change, that way you could leave your existing tabs script as is: `$('.tabs a').click(function(){ window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); });`
 });